# How can you get the RAM usage of processes in an oracle11g database?

Tags: oracle, memory-management, ram

I want to measure the RAM usage of an sql statement (e.g. a simple create or insert statement) in an oracle 11g database environment.

I tried to get it by using dbms_space, but it seems like that only gets the disk space.

I also found this site:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/m_memory_usage_percent.htm

But the statement

```
select
*
from
v$sql
where sql_text like {my table}
```

dont return the create statement.

Comment: On the top of that page there is a link [Viewing RAM for execution plan operations in Oracle9i](http://www.dba-oracle.com/m_memory_usage_percent.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comment above:

```
select operation, 
       options, 
       object_name name,
       trunc(bytes/1024/1024) "input(MB)",
       trunc(last_memory_used/1024) last_mem,
       trunc(estimated_optimal_size/1024) opt_mem, 
       trunc(estimated_onepass_size/1024) onepass_mem, 
       decode(optimal_executions, null, null, 
             optimal_executions||'/'||onepass_executions||'/'||
             multipasses_executions) "O/1/M"
  from v$sql_plan p
     , v$sql_workarea w
 where p.address=w.address(+)
   and p.hash_value=w.hash_value(+) 
   and p.id=w.operation_id(+) 
   and p.address= ( select address
                      from v$sql
                     where sql_text like '%my_table%' )
```

Comment: Doesnt work: ORA-01427, a subquery returns more than one row. furthermore the create and insert statements that i am looking for are not in v$sql.

Comment: oh and there is a typo multipasses_exections --> multipasses_executions

Comment: @Hauke ,thanks; typo fixed. The subquery returning more than one row means that v$sql has more than one list with your table name in it. You'll have to be more specific.